# SQL Query Syntax Splitter

Tags: javascript, sql

How to split these query from a single string into an array of single queries?

example:

```
"SELECT * FROM table1; SELECT * FROM table2;"
```

into

```
[
"SELECT * FROM table1;",
"SELECT * FROM table2;"
]
```

Well, I can't use javascript.split(";") because there can be semi-colon in the query as values. Like

```
"SELECT * FROM table 1 WHERE col LIKE ';'"
```

thanks.

Comment: raw sql in javascript?

Comment: If you send SQL from client to your server to be executed (even worse if through JavaScript)...change your address, obfuscate your name and pretend you're a photographer. It's _SQL injection made easy_. From client you have to collect/send parameters, query must be built server-side.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm actually making a sql terminal here. so I need the queries from html.

Comment: If you're doing a SQL terminal then use a simple regex: `subject.match(/[>#.[{](?:"[^"]*"|[^">#.[{])+/g);` as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503197/regex-split-string-on-specific-chars-outside-quotes).

Answer (score -1):

You can split using the split string "; SELECT" and add SELECT at the begining of the new strings (except the first one)

Comment: **Any** text may be contained in a SQL string. Simply string splitting isn't viable here (unless using a much more complex regex that considers also string delimiters)

Comment: Is there any libraries for this?

Comment: can't do this. It's not always "Select" it could be Insert, Update, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Use javascript.split("; ") because this is a pattern each line ends with '; ' if this is not possible in java you can create a split string function in sql

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM table 1 WHERE col LIKE ';'"` this king of query will return an error in this kind of solution.

Answer (score -2):

Here you can split it like that

```
DECLARE @Text NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Text = '"SELECT * FROM table1; SELECT * FROM table1;","SELECT * FROM table1; SELECT * FROM table2;"'
SELECT @Text = REPLACE(@Text,'"','')
SELECT @Text = 'SELECT ('''+ REPLACE(@Text,';','''); SELECT(''') + ''')'
SELECT @Text = REPLACE(@Text,'; SELECT('''')','')
PRINT @Text
EXEC (@Text)
```

If you want to print it

```
DECLARE @Text NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Text = '"SELECT * FROM table1; SELECT * FROM table1;","SELECT * FROM table1; SELECT * FROM table2;"'
SELECT @Text = REPLACE(@Text,'"','')
SELECT @Text = 'PRINT ('''+ REPLACE(@Text,';','''); PRINT(''') + ''')'
SELECT @Text = REPLACE(REPLACE(@Text,' SELECT','SELECT'),',SELECT','SELECT')
EXEC (@Text)
```

Comment: what are these called?

Comment: This is dynamic sql with some string formatting im not sure if my answer is directly what you want but i think you can achieve it in this way :)